# Advanced/complex Django ORM operation

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm having difficulty conceptualising a particular query I would like to make, based off both my own (solid intermediate) knowledge of the Django ORM and every blog post, guide and documentation I have at my disposal. But still, I'm unsure. I have been able to most of the heavy lifting in the database, with a few inefficient loops here and there to organise the data as I need it.

However, I would like to optimise it further by doing more heavy lifting in the DB and making use of Django's lazy evaluation.

To conceptualise the system:

We have the notion of a "`Job`" with "`skills`" (a ManyToManyField to the `Skill` object).

We have the notion of a `User`.

We have the notion of a `Proficiency`, an object which links a `User`, a `Skill` and provides a rating out of 10.

We have the notion of a `Candidate`, an object matches links a `User` to a `Job`, based on their scoring "proficiencies" `for` each `skill in job.skills.iterator()`.

So, out setup to "match" `Jobs` and `Users` is currently as follows:

```py
# Base users queryset:
users = User.objects.filter(
    is_staff=False,
    is_superuser=False,
    is_active=True
).prefetch_related(
    'proficiencies'
)

for user in users.iterator():
    proficiencies = user.proficiencies.filter(skill_id__in=job.skills.values_list('id', flat=True))

    # If the user doesn't match at least one proficiency to any of the job skill requirements, continue to the next loop iteration:
    if proficiencies.count() == 0:
        continue
    else:
        candidate = {
            'user': user,
            'score': 0,
            'average': 0,
            'proficiencies': []
        }

        for skill in job.skills.values('id', 'skill'):
            try:
                proficiency = proficiencies.get(skill__id=skill['id'])

                candidate['proficiencies'].append({
                    'name': skill['skill'],
                    'rating': proficiency.rating
                })

                candidate['score'] += proficiency.rating

                # The candidate average is the average of all of the "job.skills" for the Candidate:
                candidate['average'] = round((candidate['score'] / count) * 10)

            except Proficiency.DoesNotExist as ex:
                candidate['proficiencies'].append({
                    'name': skill['skill'],
                    'rating': 0
                })

        obj, _created = Candidate.objects.update_or_create(
            user=candidate.pop('user'),
            job=job,
            defaults=candidate
        )
```

For each user, we loop over each skill in the job, and see if that user has a proficiencty which matches - if they do we add to it some information about the proficiency, i.e., their rating, else we still add something - but their rating is 0 because the skill requirements hasn't been matched. Essentially, we don't require the user to have a rating for every skill requirement. We just want to give an aggregated rating.

So, I'm wondering, can we do anything within an aggregation on the users queryset? Or even an annotation/aggregation on the job.skills returning a values of OrderDicts to be used for the `update_or_create` method?

Where is the best place to optimise this for performance?

---

**Since submitting the answer, I feel this could be ok?:**

```py
for user in users.iterator():
    proficiencies = user.proficiencies.filter(skill_id__in=job.skills.values_list('id', flat=True))

    # If the user doesn't match at least one proficiency to any of the job
    # skill requirements, continue to the next loop iteration:
    if proficiencies.count() == 0:
        continue

    candidate = {
        'user': user,
        'score': 0,
        'average': 0,
        'proficiencies': []
    }

    for proficiency in proficiencies.iterator():

        candidate['proficiencies'].append({
            'name': proficiency.skill.skill,
            'rating': proficiency.rating
        })

        candidate['score'] += proficiency.rating

    for skill in job.skills.exclude(id__in=proficiencies.values_list('skill__id', flat=True))

        candidate['proficiencies'].append({
            'name': skill['skill'],
            'rating': 0
        })

    # The candidate average is the average of all of the "job.skills" for the Candidate:
    candidate['average'] = round((candidate['score'] / count) * 10)

    obj, _created = Candidate.objects.update_or_create(
        user=candidate.pop('user'),
        job=job,
        defaults=candidate
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the optimization you're looking for, but I'm wondering why you're looping over the entire user table, rather than filtering your initial query:

```py
users = User.objects.filter(
    is_staff=False,
    is_superuser=False,
    is_active=True
).filter(
    proficiencies__skill_id__in=job.skills.values_list('id', flat=True)
).prefetch_related(
    'proficiencies'
)
```

This removes the need for the proficiency count check and a bunch of database & network io.
You could also filter the prefetch_related to only include proficiencies that match the job skills.

Also, from the django documentation: "Note that if you use iterator() to run the query, prefetch_related() calls will be ignored since these two optimizations do not make sense together."  So you have to choose one or the other.